# Searching RLIKE mysql regex for two or no character

Tags: mysql, regex

How can I search in a mysql database for a pattern like this :

```
*foo??
```

Matching:

```
foo
bla foo
bla foob
bla bla foobc
```

Not matching:

```
foo bla foobcc
fooabcd
```

This is how I tried :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE name RLIKE "\\b.*foo.?.?"
```

Comment: Do you want a regex equivalent? `.*foo.{0,2}$`?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for something like that. Can this be used in MYSQL regex ?

Comment: Yes, it can. But why do you want to do it with REGEXP? REGEXP will be slower than `LIKE`. What do you need exactly?

Comment: I'm generating the query dynamically for a search field. The user can use all sort of mixed variations. Like *fo?o??oo and other variations. 
Do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: Read about mysql regex, try like `foo[[:alnum:]]{0,2}[[:>:]]`

Comment: I'm reading right now ... still confused :)

Comment: If you need to match a whole word, `[[:<:]]foo[[:alpha:]]{0,2}[[:>:]]`. If you have MySQL 8.x, just use `'\\bfoo\\w{0,2}\\b'`

Comment: Should `xfooab` match?

Comment: According to the question title, `bla foob` should not match since it has exactly 1 trailing character.

Comment: If someone downvotes the question please give a reason why you downvoted, so at least I can learn from it and not get downvoted again. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL LIKE option:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%foo__";
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%foo%";
```

> % <- SQL Wildcard ( * ) ( no char / single char / many chars)
>
> _ <- SQL Wildcard ( . ) ( single Char)

**Edit:**

For your special type:

```
select * from news WHERE text REGEXP '^(b.*)?(foo.{0,2})$';
```

The [test case](https://regex101.com/r/JvVY1T/1)

Comment: I need to find foo, fooa, fooab. As I understand this will not find fooa or foo only fooab. I need single or no chars.

Comment: The Second Statment will find  "foo", "foo a" and "bar foo"

Comment: Yes but will find also fooabcd, I need foo(and two more or no chars) foo??

Comment: You are right, I have added a regex version for your special type